# projecting the map in rviz using map_server

Tags: mapping, mapper, ros, mapserver

I want to use map_server as in this link:

http://wiki.ros.org/map_server.

I built my map using mapper3 (basic)

the map should be projected in Rviz grid and should occupy it all, the centre of the map using mapper3 ( basic) should be the centre of the Rviz grid.

The problem is that the map is always shifted (the centres are not the same ) The centre of Rviz grid is the left down corner of the map image ( the image only occupy one quarter of the grid). How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What does your TF tree look like? In addition, If you haven't properly set the origin of your map, it defaults to cell ``(0,0)`` which is the lower-left corner. See [``nav_msgs::MapMetaData``](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/MapMetaData.html). In other words, it calculates how to render the map grid by placing cell ``(0,0)`` at some offset ``x,y,z,r`` from the origin of some reference tf frame.